# cargar readr produce error

Tags: r, packages

Cuando trato de cargar (library(readr) obtengo el siguiente error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘readr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Users/davidcademartorirosso/Library/R/4.0/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
> dlopen(/Users/davidcademartorirosso/Library/R/4.0/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR
> Referenced from: /Users/davidcademartorirosso/Library/R/4.0/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
> Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
> in /Users/davidcademartorirosso/Library/R/4.0/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘readr’ was built under R version 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente es un error en las versiones 4.0.0 y 4.0.1 de R, la recomendación es actualizar R a la versión 4.0.2

La última versión la puedes descargar desde [aquí](https://cran.r-project.org/bin) te sugiero instalarla sin modificar el destino, lo cual te creará una carpeta nueva, luego obviamente tendrás que reinstalar los paquetes que uses.

Fuentes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991230/r-error-in-loading-packages-ape-and-rcpp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63088361/problems-to-load-tidyverse
- https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/after-installing-brms-rstan-or-brms-will-not-load/16798/5
- https://community.rstudio.com/t/cant-open-libraries/73421